# Stop AWK from overwriting next section in file

Tags: awk

I have the following AWK script that updates a settings.py file.

Original settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Here is the AWK script that updates the DATABASE section which works perfectly.

```
awk 'function pr(sp, k, v){    # prints key-value pair with indentation
         printf "%s\047%s\047: \047%s\047,\n",sp,k,v; 
     }
    BEGIN {
    db_user = ENVIRON["DB_USER"]
    db_pass = ENVIRON["DB_PASS"]
    db_name = ENVIRON["DB_NAME"]
    }
     /sqlite/{ sub(/sqlite[0-9]*/,"mysql",$0) }
     /NAME/{ sp=substr($0,1,index($0,"\047")-1); 
             print sp$1" \047" db_name "\047,"; 
             pr(sp,"USER", db_user); pr(sp,"PASSWORD", db_pass); 
             pr(sp,"HOST","localhost"); pr(sp,"PORT",""); next 
     }1'
```

Output of new settings.py after AWK script, which is also updating the AUTH section below.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    },
```

How can I stop AWK from overwriting the AUTH section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the following update:

```
awk 'function pr(sp, k, v){    # prints key-value pair with indentation
         printf "%s\047%s\047: \047%s\047,\n",sp,k,v; 
     }
    BEGIN {
    db_user = ENVIRON["DB_USER"]
    db_pass = ENVIRON["DB_PASS"]
    db_name = ENVIRON["DB_NAME"]
    }
     /DATABASES/{ f=1 }/AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS/{ f=0 }
     /sqlite/{ sub(/sqlite[0-9]*/,"mysql",$0) }
     /NAME/ && f{ sp=substr($0,1,index($0,"\047")-1); 
             print sp$1" \047" db_name "\047,"; 
             pr(sp,"USER", db_user); pr(sp,"PASSWORD", db_pass); 
             pr(sp,"HOST","localhost"); pr(sp,"PORT",""); next 
     }1' settings.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Small modification can solve your issue

```
/AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS/{ auth=1 }
!auth && /NAME/{
```